# Ways to invoke contract methods

Tags: solidity, contract-development, payable

I'm just starting learning development on Ethereum. So far I created a couple of local projects using truffle / web3js / react-native. Right now I started solving exercises on https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/.

I'm a little bit confused when it comes to invoking methods from the contract. In my local web3js project, when I was sending ether to payable function I was doing it like this:

```
await myContract.methods.myPayableMethod().send({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: ethValue
      });
```

On the Ethernaut I had to invoke payable method like this:

```
await ethernautContract.contribute({value: ethValue})
```

instead of this:

```
await ethernautContract.methods.contribute().send({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: ethValue
      });
```

Can anyone please explain whats the difference between the contracts, so that methods have to be invoked differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each web3 javascript library will expose the contract methods in its own way. From the intro page of Ethernaut:

> ethernaut is a TruffleContract object that wraps the Ethernaut.sol contract that has been deployed to the blockchain.

We can see that their contracts are instantiated as [@truffle/contract](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/contract) which has a method calling [procedure](http://@truffle/contract) that looks like:

```js
instance.someFunction(5);
```

On the other hand, [web3js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3), the "classic" web3 library will expose a calling procedure involving the `methods` object:

```js
myContract.methods.myMethod([param1[, param2[, ...]]]).call(options [, defaultBlock] [, callback])
```

Extra: you may also encounter usage of [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-functionsCall), a library that in this case has a similar structure to truffle's `instance.method`.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you!